# Why is there now a difference when printf("%c", '\0') in mingw and vs 2017?

Tags: c, visual-studio, mingw

I used two kinds of compiler to compile same code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    printf("%c", '\0');
    return 0;
}
```

And I will get different results compiled by mingw and vs2017. 
In mingw, I can get a white space in the console. But in vs2017, I got a character 'a' as following picture.

[image: It may not print correctly.]

Is this a bug in vs2017 or the version of my vs2017 is too low?

Comment: Rather than looking at the text and get "I can get a white space " or "character 'a' as following picture", redirect output to a file and  report its binary dump.

Comment: I get blank space in VS 2017. Check again.

Comment: @Barmak Shemirani  As a matter of fact, I have called my two friends who have VS 2017 to test this, one's program crashed, and another's also got blank space. I always get 'a', I have checked it many times at different days, or I will not ask so. Maybe this is a problem caused by my environment?

Answer (score -2):

It probably has to do with the fact that you're trying to print the `'\0'` character. That may cause an undefined behavior. You might try only printing normal characters such as `'A'`, `'t'`, `'.'`, et cetera.

Comment: NUL is not EOF. EOF is an OOB value/state (ie. -1 from various read functions).

Comment: Is it really undefined behavior? I would think it's not.

Comment: `printf("%c", '\0');` is not UB,but the glyph shown on the screen is implementation defined - by the terminal -not C.

Comment: Since `stdout` is not opened in binary mode, writing a character other than a printing character, tab or newline has unspecified effect; it might or might not be printed and it might be substituted with a different character (independent of rendering). So technically it's unspecified behaviour, not just unspecified rendering. But in practice, it will write a NUL byte which will then be rendered in some unspecified way by the terminal emulator or IDE.